# Access to ReactJS Virtual DOM from pure JS

Tags: javascript, reactjs, web-scraping

I need to parse one website, it's ReactJS single page app. If I use React Developer Tools, there are a few needed values (parameters) that not presented in real DOM (there are not rendered anywhere). Is it possible to get that values using pure JS?

Comment: you can just attach any js script on the html you are loading with react. And use any selector of the element you see on the page for fetching values. DOM manipulation not recommended with external js script.

Comment: It's not my site and not my react script. I'm injecting my own script on page just to parse it's data, not make any DOM manipulations. And some of needed parameters are not rendered by react script but I can see it in React Dev Tools.